# Is there a syntax for links with no text in Markdown?

Tags: hyperlink, markdown

I want to write

```
http://www.foo.com/
```

and get a link with the URL as the text (e.g., in HTML output). I do not want to write

```
[http://www.foo.com/](http://www.foo.com/)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you do this without the HTTP-prefix?
(this is useful for a markdown-based wiki, here you want to mark some &lt;keywords&gt; als links...

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Yes, here is the [relevant section of the documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink):

> ### AUTOMATIC LINKS
>
> Markdown supports a shortcut style for creating “automatic” links for URLs and email addresses: simply surround the URL or email address with angle brackets. What this means is that if you want to show the actual text of a URL or email address, and also have it be a clickable link, you can do this:
>
> ```
> <http://example.com/>
> ```
>
> Markdown will turn this into:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a>
> ```

Comment: FYI here on SO, plain text links work without additional tags `http://www.foo.com/` => http://www.foo.com/ - in comments the text of the link is shorthened though. and `<http://www.foo.com/>` => <http://www.foo.com/>

Comment: @Chris Can you do this without the HTTP-prefix?
(this is useful for a markdown-based wiki, here you want to mark some &lt;keywords&gt; als links...

Comment: @realbart, most wikis provide a way to easily link to pages. I would read the documentation of whatever wiki you are using and see how it handles this.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when the link is relative. For example, if you've a file `./d/a.txt`, `<d/a.txt>` _will not_ link to the file.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, handling of relative links in Markdown isn't very standard. Some implementations may work just fine, but others may not.

Comment: Its a pity that relative links don't seem to be supported. You end up with constructs like `[relative/path/to/file](relative/path/to/file)` that are obviously redundant :(

Comment: @icyerasor, support for relative links varies from tool to tool.

Comment: @Chris - didn't come across a tool that supports it yet. Supporting something like `[](some-path-or-link)` to display the rel-path/link 1:1 as text would be nice 

Answer (score 1):

If your markdown is parsed as **Github Flavored Markdown**, then text starting with a URL protocol are **already linked**. This is part of the GFM extended syntax called "Auto linked references". See the [GFM docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls#urls):

> GitHub automatically creates links from standard URLs.
>
> e.g. `Visit https://github.com`
>
> shows: Visit https://github.com

---

Note: GFM variant doesn't support this for relative links, so you'll need the redundant syntax: `[relative/path/README.md](relative/path/README.md)`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when the link is relative. For example, if you've a file `./d/a.txt`, `<d/a.txt>` _will not_ link to the file.

Comment: Its a pity that relative links don't seem to be supported. You end up with constructs like `[relative/path/to/file](relative/path/to/file)` that are obviously redundant :(

Answer (score -1):

I find this works with my IDE nicely, wrapping the link in an `<a>` tag:

```
<a>http://example.com/</a>
```

Comment: Does that actually link to `http://example.com/`? Or does it create a link to nothing? Or maybe to the current page?

Comment: "If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents." (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) So it does not link to anything.