# Markdown links without need for text link

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I would like to have links in my markdown files, without the need of specifyng a text link, such us:

```
[text link](https://sample_url)
```

Is there a way to do so without duplicating the URL?

```
[https://sample_url](https://sample_url)
```

As URLs might change over time and I would like to avoid having to change them twice.

(Sharing the question as it took me a while to find an answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a syntax for links with no text in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887301/is-there-a-syntax-for-links-with-no-text-in-markdown)

Comment: Definitely! Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<https://sample_url>
```

See https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink

It will also be rendered properly with `mkdocs`

Comment: These are called [automatic links](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink) and are clearly defined in the Markdown Syntax Rules.

Comment: This only works for external links though. Not for relative/file links. Its a pity that relative links don't seem to be supported. You end up with constructs like `[relative/path/to/file](relative/path/to/file)` that are obviously redundant :(