# Is there a shorthand Jekyll notation for a absolute HTML link where text is the same as the link?

Tags: jekyll

In Jekyll markdown, I'm trying to create an HTML link without duplicating the HTML link.
This is the currently documented approach to creating a link to another website.

```
[some text](https://example.com/some/link)
```

So in practice if I want to have the URL show up in my text I end up with:

```
[https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts)
```

This, to me, is undesirable because it makes a long URL twice as long and makes the original markup harder to follow.

My question is: **Does Jeykll have a syntax that makes the text display the same as the URL?**

## Searching for solution

I found the following that were useful but did not answer my question

- Jekyll docs - https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts
- Post saying how external links can be made https://mademistakes.com/mastering-jekyll/how-to-link/#when-do-you-use-absolute-urls
- Question about links within your Jekyll website.
  [jekyll markdown internal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629675/jekyll-markdown-internal-links)

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887301/is-there-a-syntax-for-links-with-no-text-in-markdown - the answer is yes, using a short HTML tag, try `<https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML tag shorthand would be `<https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts/>`, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887301/is-there-a-syntax-for-links-with-no-text-in-markdown).